# How to send stickers using the id (string) in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Is there any method to send stickers using the id attribute of event.file? The documentation points out to send it using the id and the access_hash of a particular sticker set and then finally using index with sticker_set to send the sticker. Since there's unique id for particular sticker stored in telegram servers, I was wondering if there's any method of using that to send stickers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetAllStickersRequest
sticker_sets = await client(GetAllStickersRequest(0))

# Choose a sticker set
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetStickerSetRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputStickerSetID
sticker_set = sticker_sets.sets[0]

# Get the stickers for this sticker set
stickers = await client(GetStickerSetRequest(
    stickerset=InputStickerSetID(
        id=sticker_set.id, access_hash=sticker_set.access_hash
    )
))

# Stickers are nothing more than files, so send that
await client.send_file('me', stickers.documents[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, but no like this. I meant to use the id of the sticker. I found a way to do it.
event.respond(file=id)

Comment: @Dominic but it will send it as an image

Comment: @Jawad no? since every media has an id field associated with them, it will use that id as reference to send the media, it could be sticker or image or gif or anything that is media. correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: GetStickerSetRequest.init() required positional argument: 'hash'. Just set hash=0 (zero) . using sticker_set.hash did not work at least in my case. example: client(GetStickerSetRequest(stickerset=InputStickerSetID(id=sticker_set.id, access_hash=sticker_set.access_hash),hash=0)  ...
More information: https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/set_stickers.html

Answer (score 0):

You must send the sticker as an `InputDocument`, specifying the sticker **id**, **access_hash** and **file_reference**.

```
from telethon import types

# some code here
await event.reply(
    file = types.InputDocument(
       id = YOUR_STICKER_ID,
       access_hash = YOUR_STICKER_ACCESS_HASH,
       file_reference = YOUR_STICKER_FILE_REFERENCE
     )
)
# more code
```

For example, reply to "/sticker" new message:

```
from telethon import events, types

# Reply to new message /sticker
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'/sticker'))
   await event.reply(
       file = types.InputDocument(
          id = YOUR_STICKER_ID,
          access_hash = YOUR_STICKER_ACCESS_HASH,
          file_reference = YOUR_STICKER_FILE_REFERENCE
       )    
    )
```